# How to get language names using Text Translation API with GetLanguageNames

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient, azure-cognitive-services

I'm not able to get the language names using Text Translation API. I get the available languages with this method:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetLanguagesForTranslateAsync()
{
    string requestUri = "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/GetLanguagesForTranslate";
    string accessToken = await this.auth.GetTokenAsync();
    string response = await this.GetAsync(requestUri, accessToken);
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(response);
    List<string> languages = new List<string>();
    foreach (XElement element in xml.Root.Descendants())
    {
        languages.Add(element.Value);
    }
    return languages;
}

private async Task<string> GetAsync(string url, string bearerToken)
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

I this case I get an XML with language codes like "en", "es", "fr" or "zh-CHT", but I want to get "english", "spanish", "french" or "chinese (traditional)". Looking [the documentation](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/text-translate.html#!/default/post_GetLanguageNames) I tried this method:

```
public async Task<List<string>> GetLanguageNamesAsync(string locale, List<string> languageCodes)
{
    string requestUri = "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/GetLanguageNames";
    string content = $"locale=en&languageCodes=en,es,fr,zh-CHT";
    string accessToken = await this.auth.GetTokenAsync();
    string response = await this.PostAsync(requestUri, accessToken, content);
    XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(response);
    List<string> languages = new List<string>();
    foreach (XElement element in xml.Root.Descendants())
    {
        languages.Add(element.Value);
    }
    return languages;
}

private async Task<string> PostAsync(string url, string bearerToken, string content)
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content));
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

The response I get with this request:

Request Error

**Error Status Code:** 'InternalServerError'

**Details:** The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the server logs for more details.

The real XML response:

```
<html version="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 2.0//EN"
      xml:lang="en"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml2.xsd"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Request Error</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <DIV id="content">
      <P class="heading1"><B>Error Status Code:</B> 'InternalServerError'</P>
      <P><B>Details: </B>The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the server logs for more details.</P>
      <!-- Padding xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-->
    </DIV>
  </BODY>
</html>
```

Do you know what is happening? Is there anything else I need to be able to make the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you can curl GetLanguages. The following works for me.

```
curl -k --data "" "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:<your Translation Text Key>" > Bearer.txt
set /p Bearer= < Bearer.txt
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %Bearer%" "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v1/http.svc/GetLanguageNames"
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %Bearer%" "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/http.svc/GetLanguagesForTranslate"
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer %Bearer%" "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?Text=Hello%%20world.&From=en&To=es"
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I'm lost, I'm trying to do it using C#, but your answer seems like console commands but I'm not sure. Maybe you can give me more detail about how to use these commands. I don't have problems with GetLanguagesForTranslate and Translate using C#, but I do have with GetLanguageNames.

Comment: Learn to use `curl` to verify proper calling of APIs. Your issue is unrelated to C#. If you had simplified the issue by eliminating C# by using `curl`, you would have found the solution in minutes, at least I found your issue in minutes. The issue is `GetLanguageNames` is not a v2 API call. It's v1 only. Your endpoint is wrong.

Comment: `curl` is great for finding such issues. Microsoft and other API providers should show `curl` commands for each of their APIs. It would save lots of time. Unfortunately Microsoft Cognitive often doesn't show a `curl` command but when they do, they're badly wrong. If I don't see a `curl` command in the documentation, I'm immediately suspicious that the API doesn't work as documented.

Comment: Thank you again, I don't know why Microsoft is using this API call with v1.